# ARM low level Interrupt handling - my link register gets killed

Tags: gcc, arm, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Target: ARM Cortex-A9
Compiler: GCC 4.9.2

Hello everyone,

I have a program with an interrupt service routine, that handles an interrupt that occurs periodically every 200ms.The ISR itself calls some subroutines, this means, it uses the link register LR.

My ISR is executed correctly, however, my program always crashes after a few seconds. The reason is the following:

When the main program calls a subroutine using the link register (BL command) and is then interrupted, the content of the link register seems to be overwritten with instruction address before the interrupt.

Now when the main program resumes after the ISR, it performs a "BX lr" command, since "BL" was used before. However, the LR has been overwritten by the interrupt and therefore the "BX lr" jumps to some wrong location.

I understand that the ISR should save the context and restore it afterwards. But since jumping to the interrupt vector already seems to overwrite the LR, how can it be saved?
(Btw.: I see that the ISR pushes the LR-4 to the stack at the start, and pops it at the end, however it pops it directly to the PC and does not bother at all to write anything usefull to the LR again)

Help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: "when the main program resumes after the ISR, it performs a "BX lr" command" - you mean you never make an exception return from IRQ mode?! Well, there's a problem right there. Remember that LR is _banked_ between modes, it's not "overwritten".

Comment: ARM has banked `sp` and `lr` for interrupts.  Also, it has a special mode called 'IRQ' (in the cpsr).  There is another 'spsr' that is saved from whatever was interrupted.  You must have 'allocated an IRQ stack' and/or switch modes from IRQ to SYSTEM at the start of the IRQ handler.  Also, a sequence like `ldmdb sp, {r0 - lr}^` or some other must restore all user registers **AND** the mode.  The 'lr' here is the 'lr_irq' which was the instruction before being interrupted (unless you have a pre-emptive OS).  What is your OS and/or give a minimal example.  You can not just code 'C' routines.